# Updating/ Pushing new data into NgRedux state

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, angular-redux, ngredux

I am new to Angular and writing service which I will be using to add new addresses (posting to a REST API).

The `saveAddress` method call returns a newly created address object on server.

Which I wanted to push into the already existing array of addresses in store. I am trying to do something like:

```
saveAddress( payload ) {
    this.httpClient.post( this.endpoint, payload).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.ngRedux.select( s => s.addresses ).subscribe( addresses => {
          let data = addresses.data.push( response )

          this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: ADD_ADDRESS_SUCCESS, payload: data })
        })
      },

      err => {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: ADD_ADDRESS_ERROR })
      }
    )
  }
```

How may I do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must never alter the `Store` (state) anywhere else than in a `reducer`. The reducers receives an action (`ADD_ADDRESS_SUCCESS`) with its payload (`{address: {...}}`) and then updates the Store with that information:

```
reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ADDRESS_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        addresses: state.addresses.push(action.payload.address)
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Note, that we always make a copy of the state and do not mutate it.
To really understand it, please read the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/articles/intro-tutorial.md) for @angular-redux/store.

For API calls you should use `Epics`: Think of an `Epic` as pipeline that transforms an action into one or multiple other actions while handling a side effect. In your case the epic reacts to the `ADD_ADDRESS_REQUEST`, makes an API call with the payload and then transforms the action into either `ADD_ADDRESS_SUCCESS` or `ADD_ADDRESS_ERROR`, depending on the result of the API call. It will never update the state itself but delegate this to the reducer handling `ADD_ADDRESS_SUCCESS` and `ADD_ADDRESS_ERROR` respectively.

Read more about epics in the corresponding [@angular-redux/store docs](https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/articles/epics.md).